# Windows universal app set focus

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10, win-universal-app

I want to set the focus automatically when "NumberEnterTextBox" lost the focus.
See my XAML code here:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Nummer eingeben: "/>
    <TextBox x:Name="NumberEnterTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Right" KeyUp="NumberEnterTextBox_KeyUp" TextChanging="NumberEnterTextBox_OnTextChanging"/>
</StackPanel>
<Viewbox x:Name="Viewbox" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Image Source="{Binding GetImageSource, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
</Viewbox>
```

Well the thing is, I tried several variations of the following snippets in my codebehind that works fine with a normal WPF application:

```
NumberEnterTextBox.Focus(FocusState.Pointer);
NumberEnterTextBox.Select(0, 0);
```

So my question is simple: How can I set the focus to the NumberEnterTextBox from my codebehind?

Comment: That is essentially what you would use (though I've used, .Focus(FocusState.Programmatic)).  The Select(0, 0) would only set the cursor position to the start of the textbox.  I have found that depending on where I put the calling in async code or in relation to dialogs can effect how well the Focus() call works.

Comment: Your code snippet works in my side. While using ` FocusState.Pointer`, you are setting focus as the direct result of a pointer interaction. What's the problem when you use this code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Well I have a solution, but I have no idea why this works in my case only within a LostFocus event:

```
private void NumberEnterTextBox_OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NumberEnterTextBox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
}
```

But thanks guys for your help!